# mongodb sync is not fast enough

Tags: nodeos, data-storage

[image]

left side is instance(using google cloud platform) running nodeos, with below spec.

> n1-standard-8 (vCPU #8, RAM 30GB, SSD 1TB)
>
> using back-up block from https://eosnode.tools/blocks
>
> mongodb-queue-size = 4096
>
> mongodb-api-cache-size = 10240
>
> filter-on = *  / trying to make block explorer, so I need filter-on as *

right side is instance running mongodb, with below spec.

> n1-highmem-4 (vCPU #4, RAM 26GB, HDD 1TB)

Currently my nodeos+mongodb is syncing 7516120 blocks (about 25% of mainnet).
I think after about 500000 blocks, sync speed isn't catching mainnet's block generartion speed(1 sec = 2 blocks).

Is it normal??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nodeos` syncing is very CPU intensive but `mongo_db_plugin` is even much more CPU and IO intensive.

I see you are using a cloud server for nodeos, which is very likely not performant enough. In my experience on AWS, the syncing speed was also slower than new block generation.

You should try a CPU enhanced instance, or more preferrably a bare-metal server for nodeos, and the higher the single-core CPU frequency, the better.

Answer (score 0):

From EOS 42 regarding the history/mongo plugin | 
Link: https://medium.com/@eos42/scalable-full-history-nodes-b4eccf113d57

> Syncing and running a full history node in early November 2018
>   required roughly 800 GB of RAM. In less than one month, the history
>   plugin now requires more than 1.5 TB of ram, nearly doubling in a
>   matter of weeks! Using the history plugin **to run a full history node
>   now costs around 30k USD**.

---

### State History Plugin

Todd Fleming from Block.one has been developing another history solution called the State History Plugin. The state history plugin solves a number of the issues experienced with the MongoDB plugin:

- Automatically handles forks and will not store any duplicated data.
- The database storage is decoupled from Nodeos. Therefore, if the database goes down it can easily be synced without stopping Nodeos or requiring a replay of the blockchain.
- Functionality that until now was not possible. Features include getting smart contract table contents at every block they are changed.
- Any future schema changes won’t require a replay of Nodoes because of the decoupled design (note: this feature will be included in future updates).

---

> in an effort to make the State History Plugin more accessible to
>   everyone, EOS42 is teaming up with Block Matrix to offer daily
>   snapshots of the State History data files, effectively allowing anyone
>   **to stand up a brand new history node in a matter of minutes** instead of
>   waiting weeks to sync.

---

Another article from Greymass covering the topic | Link: https://steemit.com/eos/@greymass/introducing-light-history-nodes-for-eos

> The state of History API nodes on the EOS network is a growing
>   concern. While we are all exploring long-term solutions, such as our
>   recent sponsorship of the development of a new History Plugin, in the
>   interim, problems continue to arise.

---

And one more from EOS Asia **"EOS Asia’s History API Announcement"**: https://medium.com/@eosasia/eos-asias-history-api-announcement-db6e66de97e7